# How to use the window.onerror as event listener in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to log the javascript errors to a file and I am using the `window.onerror` as in code below,

```
class ErrorComponent extends React.PureComponent {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        window.onerror = this.handle_error;
    }

    handle_error = (message, source, lineno, colno, error) => {
        const payload = {
            'message': message,
            'source': source,
        };
        return false;
     }

     render = () => {
         return null;
     }
 }
```

The above works fine. however, I am planning to add an event listener and `componentDidMount` and unmount life cycle hooks. like below

```
componentDidMount () {
    window.addEventListener('',this.handle_error);
}

componentWillUnMount() {
    window.removeEventListener('');
}
```

As seen from the above code, I am unsure of the event that to be used that behaves like window.onerror...if its 'error' to be used then how do I get the properties like the message, lineno, colno, and error_object...

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you try the componentDidCatch lifecycle method?

Comment: thanks but i want to use the mount and unmount lifecycles